# Swift running 3 functions one after another

Tags: swift

I was wondering if anyone could help me with running 3 functions that rely on information from the previous function to work.
This is the code I found from a previous post on how to get 2 to work:

```
func firstTask(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    // Do something

    // Call completion, when finished, success or faliure
    completion(success: true)
}

//And use your completion block like this:
firstTask { (success) -> Void in
    if success {
       // do second task if success
       secondTask()
    }
}
```

But where would the 3rd function go if you want it to run after the second one completes?
Sorry if this a really basic question, but I'm still getting the hang of programming and Swift.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use the same pattern again.  `secondTask { .........  // do third task if success } `

Comment: @Thilo That's quite an anti-pattern. It makes the functions bound to the chain. They're not reusable/modular

Comment: Well, it looks quite neat in Niko's answer below. But yeah, you probably want to pull in some library to avoid callback-hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to return the results as a return value, and chain functions together using intermediate variables.

Try to avoid overusing completion handlers. They can make code exceptionally hard to navigate. Prefer return values whenever possible.

```
func produceASCIIHexCodes() -> [UInt8] {
    return [0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21]
}

func convertToUnicodeScalars(hexCodes: [UInt8]) -> [UnicodeScalar] {
    return hexCodes.map(UnicodeScalar.init)
}

func convertToCharacters(unicodeScalars: [UnicodeScalar]) -> [Character] {
    return unicodeScalars.map(Character.init)
}

func createString(fromCharacters characters: [Character]) -> String {
    return String(characters)
}

func display(string: String) {
    print(string)
}

let hexCodes = produceASCIIHexCodes()
let unicodeScalars = convertToUnicodeScalars(hexCodes: hexCodes)
let characters = convertToCharacters(unicodeScalars: unicodeScalars)
let string = createString(fromCharacters: characters)
display(string: string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it like this (Tested in playground)

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func firstTask() -> Bool {
    // Do something
    print("First task")
    return true // change this to determine the task success or not
}

func secondTask() -> Bool {
    // Do something
    print("Second task")
    return true // change this to determine the task success or not
}

func thirdTask() {
    // Do something
    print("Third task")
}

let thirdBlock: (_ success: Bool) -> () = { success in
    guard success else { return }
    thirdTask()
}

let secondBlock: (_ success: Bool) -> () = { success in
    guard success else { return }
    let success = secondTask()
    thirdBlock(success)
}

let firstBlock: () -> () = {
    let success = firstTask()
    secondBlock(success)
}

firstBlock()
```

You can save yourself from this callback hell with learning Reactive Programming, either with [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) or [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift).